# Parity Ethereum Metamask

Tags: metamask, private-blockchain, openethereum

I have setup one test node on my machine. When trying to connect to Metamask, I keep on receiving below messages on the node console and am unable to connect with node using Metamask.

```
2019-06-14 14:48:32  Accepted a new tcp connection from 127.0.0.1:54536.

2019-06-14 14:48:33  Accepted a new tcp connection from 127.0.0.1:54538.

2019-06-14 14:48:34  Accepted a new tcp connection from 127.0.0.1:54540.

2019-06-14 14:48:34  Accepted a new tcp connection from 127.0.0.1:54541.

2019-06-14 14:48:34  Accepted a new tcp connection from 127.0.0.1:54542.
```

Comment: Having the same issue with my netstats client. What Parity version is that? Probably a bug in Parity.